# Aborted error message in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a windows service hosting WCF, with its bindings configured as follows:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingReliableMessaging"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="23:59:59"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The client that connects has similar binding on it.

I'm using a subscription method to send out messages, this is this broadcast code:

```
    public void NotifyServer(EventDataType eventData)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {                
            var inactiveClients = new List<string>();

            // Broadcast to all the clients bar the one sending it
            //
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {

                if (client.Key != eventData.ClientName)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Send the message to the current client
                        //
                        client.Value.BroadcastToClient(eventData);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // If we can't access the current clients callback method, 
                        // we add them to the inactive clients list, as they've probably lost their connection.
                        //
                        inactiveClients.Add(client.Key);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (inactiveClients.Count > 0)
            {
                // Remove any clients that we couldn't get to
                //
                foreach (var client in inactiveClients)
                {
                    clients.Remove(client);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This has been in use for quite some time, just recently the messages being sent have gotten bigger (now about 113K) and I'm getting the following error message:

```
   The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.
```

I have the sizes all maxed out as well as the timeouts and the clients have not dropped off. Any suggestions as to the cause?

Rob

As Requested, here are the config files:

Client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="ARIA.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="AriaClient.Log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date (#%property{pid}) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IBroadcasterService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="23:59:59"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMathsEngineService">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://MARSH:8080/MetricBroadcast" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IBroadcasterService" contract="MetricBroadcast.IBroadcasterService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IBroadcasterService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="s_aria@racing.lc" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://MARSH:8088/MathsEngine" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMathsEngineService" contract="MathsEngineService.IMathsEngineService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IMathsEngineService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="s_aria@racing.lc" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AriaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Aria.csdl|res://*/Model.Aria.ssdl|res://*/Model.Aria.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MARSH\SQL2012;initial catalog=Aria;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="AMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.AMS.csdl|res://*/Model.AMS.ssdl|res://*/Model.AMS.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=BIC-SVR-AMS1;initial catalog=ToroRossoAMS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <applicationSettings>
    <ARIA.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="MedusaPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>\\bic-svr-aria01\Medusa</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogHeartbeat" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="UseRepository" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
    </ARIA.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
 <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="MetricBroadcast.Log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings.TargetConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=BIC-SVR-TSTARIA01\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Aria;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=XXXX" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="BindingReliableMessaging"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="23:59:59"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="BroadcasterServiceBehavior" name="MetricBroadcast.BroadcasterService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingReliableMessaging" contract="MetricBroadcast.IBroadcasterService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://BIC-SVR-TSTARIA01:8080/MetricBroadcast" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!-- A behavior definition  -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BroadcasterServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogXML" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
    </MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you post the server and client configuration files?

Comment: I've added the config files for the client and server as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, its time for a bit of a red face - it turned out I was editing the wrong config file - its been set up for debug and release environments and I was editing the core one which gets overwritten when compiled.

Doh.

I'll be in the corner with a pointy hat on.

Rob